# When is the best time to move daffodil bulbs?

Tags: transplanting, bulbs, daffodils

A while back, I planted a patch of daffodils in my lawn. I've regretted it ever since when I have to mow around the plants after they've bloomed, it looks a mess with only the leaves after the blooms have gone and the grass suffers after the leaves have gone, too.

When is the best time to fork-up the bulbs and transplant them to a border? They're still in-leaf at the moment so it'll be easier to find the little jokers but should I wait until all the 'goodness' has returned to the bulb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [wikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Transplant-Daffodils):

> **Divide and transplant daffodils at the end of the growing season.** Wait until the growing season is over before you begin. When the growing season is over, the foliage will wither away and turn yellow or brown. This usually happens in the late spring or early summer.
>
> If you wait much later in the year you may not be able to find your daffodils, as the plant will be dormant and any visible signs of it hidden under the ground. Because of this, try to take action when there’s still some of the plant visible above ground.

(ie exactly as you thought - though, in my opinion, you should be more tolerant of them where they are! Tying the leaves in a knot/s may mitigate some of the untidiness.)

Comment: Hi pnuts. I'm not sure expressing that OP should be more tolerant and leave the daffodils where they are is helpful, even though you were clear it was your opinion. fluffy mart specifically asked for instructions for moving them.

Comment: I didn't mean to insinuate that you hadn't provided excellent transplanting instructions. I meant to acknowledge that in my first comment but forgot. Sorry about that! I also forgot to upvote, so I did it now.

Comment: I get what you mean about opinions, and that's a great link!